# Github Pages not loading my project

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to create a GitHub Pages for one of my existing repositories. When I click on "Your site is published at ..." I just get a blank screen. Here is the link to the site: https://mrcj101111.github.io/Clipboard/

Comment: Have you built any files to be auto injected?

Comment: @Any Moose, Yes the project works fine if I launch it through a local server.

Comment: You might start a new question. Asking why an app will not load in a GitHub page, as this question will not draw the correct response.

Comment: Thanks, will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is correct. Your Body is empty, in the below example I added an h1 header with the a value of "geckos-23".

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>geckos-23</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>geckos-23</h1>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Any Moose, I see it works now when I click the link, but it is suppose to run the whole app.. Do you perhaps know why this won't work?